# server.Databases[databaseName].Drop(); fails in MSTest

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, smo

The following exception is thrown:

Error Message:  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Drop failed for Database '4d982a46-58cb-4ddb-8999-28bd5bb900c7'.  --->  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. --->  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot drop database "4d982a46-58cb-4ddb-8999-28bd5bb900c7" because it is currently in use.

Any idea what caused this?

Is it possible to call a SMO function to finalize any running Transact-SQL statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a guess, I wonder if your connection pool is counting against you - i.e. you have previously executed some commands on  a `SqlConnection` that is now being kept around for re-use. You could try disabling pooling? (pooling=false in the connection string, IIRC).

Also - have you been careful to close all your commands/connections/readers etc? Ideally via `using`? As a last resort, you could try using T-SQL to kill all the other spids from your machine - hacky, but it might work.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Server.KillDatabase(string database)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.killdatabase.aspx) method which closes all open connections for you.